# How can I create a traceability matrix between User Story and Test Case?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm working for a french company and we're using Team Foundation Server 2017 and I would like to know if it's possible to create an Excel file in order to make a synthesis of all links between User Story and Test Case ? If it's possible, how can I do that ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

No, the traceability matrix is not supported in Excel (with TFS) or TFS. You can use work item queries with direct links for that purpose ([Use direct links to view dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies)):

1. Mapping US to tests:

[image]

2. US without test:

[image]

3. Mapping test to US

[image]

Additionally, you can try to create Power Bi report: [Work items with direct links sample reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-directlinks?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi)

Comment: Is there any other solution to made a traceability matrix ?
Or something that can produce a report with all links between User story and Test Case ?

Comment: @Léo **Modern Requirements** supports such solution https://www.modernrequirements.com/video-series/traceability-matrices-3/#:~:text=Intersection%20Traceability%20Matrix-,Traceability%20Matrices%20in%20Azure%20DevOps,requirements%2C%20and%20ensure%20Test%20Coverage.

Comment: How can I found the field "Team Project" ? Because when I would like to do a query I can't find it

Comment: @Léo you can skip it if you create a query only for the current project. To use `Team Project` field, check `Query across projects` option in the top right corner of the query editor.